# iOS Twitter Integration

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to integrate twitter in my application, mostly that will use for login purpose, I want to implement it like following case

1. Check if there are any twitter account already linked with phone use that with reverse authentication
2. If no account linked, Use some OAuth library for twitter and make authentication with that

Anyone have idea about any existing library/framework doing the same ? Thanks

P.S : Minimum supported iOS version would be iOS6

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code: (If no account is found from settings, then this will take your application to settings screen of device):

```
- (IBAction)loginWithTwitterBtn:(id)sender
{
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        //yes user is logged in
        accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             // Did user allow us access?
             if (granted == YES)
             {
                 // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
                 NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                 ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

                 // Set the cell text to the username of the twitter account
                 NSString *userID = [[acct valueForKey:@"properties"] valueForKey:@"user_id"];

             }
         }];
    }
    else
    {
        //show tweeet login prompt to user to login
        TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        //hide the tweet screen
        viewController.view.hidden = YES;

        //fire tweetComposeView to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view on iOS5.1
        viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
        };
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

        //hide the keyboard
        [viewController.view endEditing:YES];
    }
}

//*******************
```

Comment: Checking now, Thanks Btw !!

Comment: Its giving lots of deprecated warnings, And not showing login prompt when no account is configured !

Comment: Actully I have implemented it in iOS 6. And as I added a note at the top of answer, if it doesnot find any twitter account it will show alert to take user to settings screen..

Comment: I want to implement it in iOS 6 + iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aryansbtloe/LoginViaSocialMedias

This is an example project for adding login via facebook,twitter,google plus and four square support to your ios application.